# When assert.equal(innerText,"value") fails,cucumber stops abruptly

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, chai, cucumberjs

'When I try to assert some web elements,if assertion fails cucumber stops execution  with error

```
AssertionError:'567'='abc'
```

**Feature file:**

```
Scenario: Validation of button
    Given I hit login page
    When login page gets loaded
    Then validate text on button

Scenario:Login to the page
    Given user provide login details
    When clicks on login button
    Then sign in the user
```

Cucumber stops abruptly and result of passed steps is not shown.

If assertion fails,I want to go cucumber to execute next steps .please help and thanks.'

**Update with step example:**

```js
this.Then(/^Validate text on button$/, function() {
  var textonbutton = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("it's xpath"));
  textonbutton.getText('innerText').then(function(innerText) {
    return assert.equal(innerText, "567");
  });
});
```

Comment: My code:

'this.Then(/^Validate text on button$/,function(){ 
Var textonbutton = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("it's xpath"));
textonbutton.getText('innerText').then(function(innerText){
return assert.equal(innerText,"567");
});
});'

Comment: Please Edit your post and add your code to id.

Comment: You are tagging with protractor, but are you also using protractor? If so, please provide a complete code example of: the config file, the step implementation. Tnx in advance

Comment: Abruptly means?

Comment: Maybe try getText() instead of getText('innerText') ?